# iOS dateFormatter dateFromString month issue

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdateformatter

Hopefully this is just a quick one and I'm missing something simple...

I've got an NSDateFormatter, which I'm using to convert the string **2011-11-10** into a Date object.

```
NSDateFormatter *fmtDate = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[fmtDate setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-DD"];

// input of 2011-11-10, output of 2011-01-10 00:00:00 +0000        
[appointment setDate:[fmtDate dateFromString:
  [tempAppointment objectForKey:@"date"]
]];
```

The return from the NSDateFormatter is stored in a managedObjectContext. My problem is that the dateFormatter is returning the date as **2011-01-10 00:00:00 +0000**

Why is it reducing the month from Nobvember to January? It's retaining the year and the day fine, but not the month.

Do I need to include the hours when I store the date? Or is it something to do with the format I set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your date format string is not correct using YYYY.  Try yyyy-M-d or yyyy-MM-dd

```
NSString *dateString = @"2011-11-10";

NSDateFormatter *fmtDate = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[fmtDate setDateFormat:@"yyyy-M-d"];

NSDate *date = [fmtDate dateFromString:dateString];
NSLog(@"date: %@", date);
```

Outputs:

```
2011-11-10 20:01:40.638 Craplet[81514:707] date: 2011-11-10 05:00:00 +0000
```

See:

http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-10.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Answer (score 2):

Try the format @"yyyy-MM-dd" for the format as specified [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1) in the "Use Format Strings to Specify Custom Formats" section. It has an example and list YYYY as a common mistake.

Comment: That's made no difference, I'm still getting 2011-01-10 00:00:00 +000

Comment: Ah I missed the d! Right, I changed YYYY -> yyyy but it was the DD -> dd that fixed it. Thanks!